# getting key count which matches a pattern

Tags: redis

I have used following command to get the key count which matches particular pattern,
 `redis-cli -p 6379 KEYS "key_pattern" | wc -l`

but the results have some mismatch with actual values.There are six keys in my db.

[image]

but I got 5 as the result.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here..?

Comment: is the output correct when just run redis-cli -p 6379 KEYS "*" ?

Comment: @MallowFox, yes.

Comment: verify the keys count using:                                                                     
redis-cli  info keyspace  | grep -oP '(?<=keys\=)[0-9]*(?=,)'